# How to integrate multiple IP cameras into Android programmatically?

Tags: android, cgi, android-wifi, android-networking, ip-camera

I am new in android networking. Now I am doing an **Android network related project**. In this project **I want to integrate 6 IP cameras into my project and all cameras stream simultaneously**. This **IP cameras are Wi-Fi enabled cameras**. The problem is here, **how we connect multiple wifi devices into an Android device ?** Only we can connect single Wi-Fi at a time. But one way is **Wi-Fi direct or Hotspot**. But **how the IP camera identify and connect mobile hotspot ?**

This is the cgi command given by the client to **get Wi-Fi scan result**

**get_wifi_scan_result.cgi**

```
   Description: Gets the camera results of search for wireless networks
Certification: administrator
Syntax: /get_wifi_scan_result.cgi
Returns:
ap_number : Refers to the search for how many SSID , The following variable groups, with the first group, for example:
ap_ssid[0]：ssid
ap_mode[0]：0->infra 1->adhoc
ap_security[0]：
                0->WEP-NONE
                1->WEP
                2->WPA-PSK TKIP
                3->WPA-PSK AES 
                4->WPA2-PSK TKIP
                5->WPA2-PSK AES
ap_dbm0[0]:  
ap_channel:
```

Answer (score 0):

Android cannot currently connect to more than 1 Wi-Fi provider.

Try connecting all cameras to a single router, and then the Android device uses the same router.

Beware that this might not work on some Wi-Fi cameras that behave as mini web servers such that the router has to connect **to** them (via RTSP/RTMP).